# What triggers the ClassNotFoundExcption, only on the first call, when packing facelets 1.1.15 with jsf2?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I'm getting on the very first call to my facelet a classnotfound exception. On the second call it works without problems. I use jboss 6 with mojarra 2.0 and facelets 1.1.15 B1 which i pack into the web-inf/lib folder.

```
 ERROR [org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter] Exception in the filter chain: javax.servlet.ServletException: com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/html/HtmlComponentHandler
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321) [:2.0.3-]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206) [:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290) [:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388) [:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515) [:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:593) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_17]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/html/HtmlComponentHandler
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616) [:1.6.0_17]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:585) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:156) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.doLoadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:141) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:132) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:260) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1152) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) [:1.6.0_17]
    at org.jboss.classloader.plugins.loader.ClassLoaderToLoaderAdapter.loadClass(ClassLoaderToLoaderAdapter.java:184) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:260) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1152) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) [:1.6.0_17]
    at com.sun.facelets.util.ReflectionUtil.forName(ReflectionUtil.java:36) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.createClass(TagLibraryConfig.java:291) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.endElement(TagLibraryConfig.java:210) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:198) [:1.6.0_17]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:407) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:431) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:87) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:104) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:218) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:149) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:100) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:517) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100) [:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176) [:3.3.3.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309) [:2.0.3-]
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.html.HtmlComponentHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303) [:1.6.0_17]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) [:1.6.0_17]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:284) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1152) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316) [:1.6.0_17]
    ... 98 more

20:31:17,486 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/myWebApp].[Faces Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.html.HtmlComponentHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303) [:1.6.0_17]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) [:1.6.0_17]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:284) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1152) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616) [:1.6.0_17]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:585) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:156) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.doLoadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:141) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:132) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:260) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1152) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) [:1.6.0_17]
    at org.jboss.classloader.plugins.loader.ClassLoaderToLoaderAdapter.loadClass(ClassLoaderToLoaderAdapter.java:184) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:260) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1152) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) [:1.6.0_17]
    at com.sun.facelets.util.ReflectionUtil.forName(ReflectionUtil.java:36) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.createClass(TagLibraryConfig.java:291) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.endElement(TagLibraryConfig.java:210) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:198) [:1.6.0_17]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:407) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:431) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:87) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:104) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:218) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:149) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:100) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:517) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100) [:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176) [:3.3.3.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309) [:2.0.3-]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206) [:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290) [:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388) [:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515) [:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:593) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_17]
```

Comment: I think you should mention you're doing this for RichFaces 3.3 compatibility. It's a rather unusual setup otherwise. Did you disable the build-in view handler as per JBoss' instructions?

Comment: how did you know that I'm doing it for richfaces 3.3.3? *shiver*

Comment: I just read a previous question of you where you mentioned this. Besides, it's about the only reason in the whole wide world to ever do this. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by outdated tomahawk libraries *blush*. Still an odd error. So solution was to replace tomahawk-1.1.6.jar and tomahawk-facelets-taglib.jar with tomahawk20-1.1.11.jar from [the download page of tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html)